# Asynchronous DOM manipulation with JavaScript and ColdFusion templates?

Tags: javascript, excel, asynchronous, coldfusion

I just started using ColdFusion and I've come up with a problem I'm not sure how to tackle.

So, right now I have Cold Fusion serving HTML/JS templates to the browser. These templates also pull in data from session data and I used them in the templates as conditionals/variables.

In one of these templates, I am generating a `.xlsx` file, using `<cfspreadsheet>`. It is represented by a button on webpage, when clicked downloads the file. The problem is that the page/template being served takes 5+ seconds to load, since it looks like it is taking 5+ seconds to generate the `.xlsx` file with the correct data.

So my question is there a way to load this particular page, but make the generation of the `.xlsx` asynchronous. So in practice, load the particular page, the download button is disabled, the generation of the `.xlsx`file completes, download button is enabled.

Comment: Consider separating the web page from the spread sheet generation. Have the web page generate and show its data. When the page loads have it fire off a web service to generate the `.xlsx`. When that web service completes have it enable the button. The key is how cleaning you can split the two. Without code it is hard to tell how well it splits.

Comment: The `cfflush` tag allows you to render html content to the browser while other code is running.  The `cfthread` tag allows you to run code asynchronously.  However, it might be prudent to see why the slow code is slow.  Maybe it can be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

Render page with button disabled. Generate the xslx in a different CFML file that is loaded asynchronously via AJAX using your Javascript library of choice (raw Javascript, jQuery, Vue, etc). When it completes enable the download button.